# How to narrow types based on a single property test

Tags: typescript

```
export type ZeroTurn = {
  zeroturn: string
}

export type OneTurn = {
  oneturn: string
}

export type Turn =
    | ZeroTurn
    | OneTurn      
                                                               
export function isZeroTurn(_: Turn): is ZeroTurn = {
    return ((_ as ZeroTurn).zeroturn) !== undefined);
}
```

I have a few of these cases where some types have a single specific property, and I want to narrow the type from a union type. Is there a pattern I can extract to code this more precisely? Without writing a test that tests it's specific property for every type.

I am thinking making another type for property names and using in somehow.

Something like this:

```
function makeNarrower<A, B extends A>(property: string) {
  return (_: A): is B => {
    return (property in _)
  };
}
```

Comment: `zeroturn in _` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have generic solution:

```js
const hasProperty = <T, P extends string>(obj: T, prop: P): obj is T & Record<P, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)


const foo = <T,>(arg: T) => {
    if (hasProperty(arg, 'name')) {
        const check = arg // T & Record<"name", unknown>

    }
}
```